# Override method with different return type in c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, covariance

I am beginner in c++, so excuse if my question is dumb. I have 4 classes: `ProgramNodeBase`, `ProgramNode`, `FunctionBase`, `Function`. `ProgramNode` derives from `ProgramNodeBase` and `Function` derives from `FunctionBase`. `ProgramNodeBase` has vector of pointers to `FunctionBase` and method that can return item from it. Is it possible to override this method in derived class `ProgramNode` in such way that it would return `Function` instead of `FunctionBase`? I looked at some answers here, but didn't found any where return type derived.

I am asking because I have methods that need `Function` and this can only return `FunctionBase` so there is need of some casting when I want to call it. Is there some easy way to handle this?

This is just snippet of my code, but it covers the problem I am encountering. I hope that this question is clear and not very trivial.

```
// ProgramNodeBase.h
#include <vector>

class FunctionBase;

class ProgramNodeBase
{
    protected:
        std::vector<FunctionBase*> m_edgeFn;
    public:
        ProgramNodeBase();
        virtual ~ProgramNodeBase();
        virtual FunctionBase* GetEdgeFunction(unsigned int position);
};

// ProgramNodeBase.cpp
#include "ProgramNodeBase.h"

ProgramNodeBase::ProgramNodeBase() { }
ProgramNodeBase::~ProgramNodeBase() { }

FunctionBase* ProgramNodeBase::GetEdgeFunction(unsigned int position)
{
    if (position < m_edgeFn.size())
    {
         return m_edgeFn[position];
    }

    return nullptr;
}

// FunctionBase.h
class FunctionBase
{
    public:
        FunctionBase();
        virtual ~FunctionBase();
};

// FunctionBase.cpp
#include "FunctionBase.h"

FunctionBase::FunctionBase() { }
FunctionBase::~FunctionBase() { }

// ProgramNode.h
#include "ProgramNodeBase.h"

class ProgramNode : public ProgramNodeBase
{
    public:
        ProgramNode();
        ~ProgramNode();
        // ??? Function* ProgramNodeBase::GetEdgeFunction(unsigned int position)
        FunctionBase* GetEdgeFunction(unsigned int position) override;
};

// ProgramNode.cpp
#include "ProgramNode.h"

ProgramNode::ProgramNode() { }
ProgramNode::~ProgramNode() { }

// ??? Function* ProgramNodeBase::GetEdgeFunction(unsigned int position)
FunctionBase* ProgramNodeBase::GetEdgeFunction(unsigned int position)
{
    if (position < m_edgeFn.size())
    {
         return m_edgeFn[position];
    }

    return nullptr;
}

// Function.h
#include "FunctionBase.h"

class Function : public FunctionBase
{
    public:
        Function();
        ~Function();
};

// Function.cpp
#include "Function.h"

IFunction::Function() { }
IFunction::~Function() { }
```

Comment: What error does the compiler give ?

Comment: @Steve that's right for overloading, not overriding. C++ *has* covariant return types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, C++ *does* support covariant return types with raw pointers. So the following *is* possible:

```
class ProgramNodeBase
{
public:
  virtual FunctionBase* GetEdgeFunction(unsigned int position);
};


class ProgramNode : public ProgramNodeBase
{
public:
  Function* GetEdgeFunction(unsigned int position) override;
};
```

For this to work, the definition of `Function` must be available where the overrider is declared—the compiler must be able to verify that the return type is actually covariant.

Of course, you will have to provide an appropriate implementation for the overrider.

Comment: I tried, but I am getting many errors like this: `error C2555: 'ProgramNode::GetEdgeFunction': overriding virtual function return type differs and is not covariant from 'ProgramNodeBase::GetEdgeFunction'`

Comment: @benderto Edited; does that address the issue?

Comment: yes :) thank you. I had  `#include "Function.h"` in `ProgramNode.cpp` and only got `class Function;` in `ProgramNode.h`. Everything is working when I changed it. Maybe just what if I would have circular dependency? Then I would have to use `class Function;` and cannot override that method. Is that right?

Comment: @benderto Yes, if they depend on each other for their definitions, you cannot do this.